# MVC4 Razor syntax one-to-many nested lists

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, one-to-many

I'd be very grateful if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong. I'm using MVC 4, database first with an edmx file, two simple tables trying to list a set of child results under a parent result.

the controller code, simplified:

```
 var query = db.Childtablemodel.Include(c => c.ParentTablemodel);
 return View(query.ToList());
```

The view, which is IEunumerable:

```
enter code here@{ 
foreach (var itm in Model)
{
 <div>

  @itm.ParentTable.DisplayName
  <ul>        
   <li>
    <span> @itm.City </span> <span> @itm.State</span>
   </li>

   </ul>

</div>
 }
}
```

the results repeat the parent name for each child

Company 1

Houston TX

Company 1

Austin TX

Where what I want is

Company 1

Houston TX

Austin TX

I am following the [Contoso University tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and so chose the child model for my controller (after a discouraging attempt to create these groupings in a parent-model- based controller). The edmx model  does show the proper navigation properties and they are present in the generated class files. But when I look at a trace of my query, I see that it is using an inner join, which explains my results -- but utterly baffles me!

Comment: Thank you very much @Travis J. That did indeed take care of the problem. I had tried Groupby in my controller code and the debugger threw a fit; I never thought to try it in razor! I haven't accumulated a sufficient reputation to vote up your answer, but I hope others do!

Comment: That is okay. I am glad that the code worked for you :) Although you cannot upvote, you can at least accept the answer by clicking the green check mark if it is correct. You may want to review some of your other questions for correct answers as well (it is considered common courtesy to accept answers which were correct).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Check checked.  Not sure any of my other questions were answered, but I'll check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to want to use linq's groupby to do that.

```
@{ 
 foreach (var parent in Model.GroupBy(m => m.ParentTable.DisplayName))
 {
  <div>
   @parent.Key
   @foreach( var itm in parent )
   {
    <ul>        
     <li>
      <span> @itm.City </span> <span> @itm.State</span>
     </li>
    </ul>
   }
  </div>
 }
}
```